# Translate to a distance then rotate and go back to earlier position on x-axis in unity

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine

I am considering a plane on which i have placed an image and I want this plane to move along x-axis.My problem here is that when i click on the plane it should move to a certain distance and then flip or rotate the plane and after the rotation it should move back to the original location.For example: If image is of a toy I want the toy to move 5 units to the left then the image of the toy should rotate to 180 and then again move back 5 units to right to its original position and this process should happen when i click on the plane/image.I am new to programming and also unity so i am clueless how should i do that?Any thoughts?Please let me know.

Is there any simpler way to do it????

```
var moveforward;
function Start(){
moveforward = false;
}
function Update(){
if(moveforward)
forwardmovement();
 else if(!moveforward)
 backwardmovement();
 }
   function forwardmovement(){
   transform.position.x += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
   yield WaitForSeconds(1);
   moveforward = false;
   }
  function backwardmovement(){
  transform.position.x -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;;
  yield WaitForSeconds(1);
  moveforward = true;
   }
```

this lets my image to move along x axis but after it reaches 1 unit i want it to rotate and then move -1 unit back to its original position.(Am i doing it wrong??)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can achieve this by using [Vector3.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html). Lerp moves your object smoothly. Note that the input has a from- and to location. Just add 5 at the x-axis on the to- Vector3.

As for rotating, use [Quaternion.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html). This will rotate your object smoothly. After you have done this, use Vector3.Lerp again to move it back.

You say you want to achieve this by clicking on the object. You can get the click by `Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")`. Just use a "[Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) (Input.mousePosition);". With that you can check if the RayCast hitted something and what the name of that object is. If it's the toy, move the toy.